# Redactor customisation not showing in Redactor text field

Tags: craft3, redactor

I've set up a custom redactor .json file which works and shows up on the dropdown, however, whenever I'm selecting one of the options the text in the field isn't updating to the chosen style.

I've attached some images so you can see what I mean:

[image: JSON of custom redactor type]

[image: CraftCMS redactor dropdown with options shown]

[image: highlighted lorem ipsum text in a span tag with a class of red]

[image: lorem ipsum text]

---

It works on the front end but I'm a little puzzled why it's not showing on this side.

This is the first time I've done custom redactor options before so I could've potentially missed a step on getting it to work? I've had a look in the docs and couldn't find what I was looking for so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Hmm just a guess, have you added some CSS to the CP to style ".red" ?

Comment: Haha, yes I have. Everything is in a custom CSS file and hooked up.